# canvas circle changing top position

Tags: html, css, canvas, html5-canvas

i am drawing circle using canvas. please check my below code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

<script>
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(100, 75, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.stroke();
</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

code is working perfectly. i need to add margin, top of the circle. not for canvas margin. this margin should for only circle.
[Clock Demo](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/canvas_clock_start.asp)

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand your question, are you looking to move the circle in the canvas or just make it bigger? You can move it by changing the 100 and 75 values for position and the 50 for radius

Comment: use `padding-top` to canvas?

Comment: i want to add margin top for the circle.

Comment: not for the canvas. i need to add it to circle

Comment: Change the 75 value to 100 that will push it downwards.

Comment: @Canvas, please check my demo link. i need to push clock downwards.. can u help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use context.translate and provide it the X offset and Y offset. So before you draw to the canvas you can set the translate, draw what you want and then reset it if required.

To move the clock downwards you can do this

```
function drawClock() {
  // This will move the clock down by 100 pixels
  ctx.translate(0, 100);
  drawFace(ctx, radius);
  drawNumbers(ctx, radius);
  drawTime(ctx, radius);
  // This will reset the translate position to 0, 0. If you don't it will begin to move the clock each update
  ctx.translate(0, -100);
}
```

You could set the ctx.translate so it will always be offset, but I'm not sure if you wanted to draw anything else.